# Retrieve JSON from javascript to php (OpenCart controller)

Tags: javascript, json, opencart

There is a nice `JSON` object in `console.log`, but can't seem to retrieve it in controller.

```
        function checkOut(data) {
        $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=sale/customer/checkout&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&customer_id=<?php echo $customer_id; ?>&products=' + data,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: 'products=' + encodeURIComponent(data), 
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() {

            $('.success, .warning').remove();
            $('#button-checkout').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#checkout').before('<div class="attention"><img src="view/image/loading.gif" alt="" /> <?php echo $text_wait; ?></div>');
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#button-checkout').attr('disabled', false);
            $('.attention').remove();
        },
        success: function(html) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#checkout').html(html);
        }
    });
}
```

Sending `data` via get only seems to send a `string`, `[object Object]`.

Change the dataType to `json` and all the `html` in result page disappears.

Experimented with `$.parseJSON(data);`, which returns null value in console.log.

What's the method to retrieve the data object so it can be `json_decode($data, TRUE)`d and available as a php array?

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=sale/customer/checkout&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&customer_id=<?php echo $customer_id; ?>',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        products: data
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, man. it's giving me an `Unexpected token ILLEGAL` error on`url: 'index.php?route=sale/customer/checkout&token=' + 3f93699ccee7bda241af121f7aee4db2 + '&customer_id=' + 2 + '&products=' + data,`. I also tried adding a `'` at the end of the url line thinking maybe that was the issue.

Comment: alert('index.php?route=sale/customer/checkout&token=' + <?php echo $token; ?> + '&customer_id=' + <?php echo $customer_id; ?> + ' &products=' + data'); this and let me know what you are getting in that

Comment: now we're getting somewhere. the `'<?php echo $var; ?>'` needed to be in single quotes and now it retirns `index.php?route=sale/customer/checkout&token=3f93699ccee7bda241af121f7aee4db2&customer_id=2&products=[object Object]`

Comment: But console says `DATA is not defined`

Comment: try to JSON.stringify(data) and retrive using string in backend

Comment: I have edited this answer. Now it should work straight away. The URL string does not need to be split because of PHP variables - they can be just echoed inside the JS string. The products part with the data is removed from the query string and put as the `data` property value. Since it is `data: {products: data}` it will be posted as an object and JSON encoded without the need to stringify nor explicitly encode. Retrieve on PHP side by getting the `products` index from POST and `json_decode`ing it.

Comment: but as it's written above, as long as the function is being called, it should open an alert box that contains `data` (or at least `object Object`), right? I get the json in the console BEFORE the .ajax call, but nothing after it. no error, either. just nothing.

Comment: change products: data this to products: "someothername", do not use same name for response and request